# Vertically align a child div to a parent div in a responsive website

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically align the child div to the bottom of the parent div. This is for a responsive website, so I understand there are ways in using a table, but none of it seems to provide me with an exact answer that would perform in the correct way across modern browsers, including iOS. Any help would be amazing! Thanks

```
#parent {
width: 32%;
height: 242px;
background-color: red;
}

#child {
width: 100%;
height: 57px;
background-color: green;
}

#text {
background-color: yellow;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
}


<div class='box' id='parent'>
    <div class='box' id='child'>
        <div class='box' id='text'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:relative;` on the parent and `position:absolute; bottom:0;` on the child

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/8eGK7/)

```
#parent {
    position: relative;    
width: 32%;
height: 242px;
background-color: red;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
width: 100%;
height: 57px;
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks so much! I've tried so many other ways. Especially it being so simple and clean!

Comment: no problem.  just hook me up with that checkmark :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use :after solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class='box' id='parent'>
    <div class='box' id='child'>
        <div class='box' id='text'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    width: 32%;
    height: 242px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#parent:after {
    content:'';
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: green;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#text {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Here the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Pcan/)

Comment: nice solution! i've always tried adding the :after pseudo-element to the child :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent a `position: relative;`, and the child `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0;`

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 32%;
    height: 242px;
    background-color: red;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/rLhdc/

Answer (score 0):

I have a neat way to vertically (and horizontally if needed) align something to the parent which is always responsive.  The child element doesn't need an explicit width or height, so it can also scale if you want.  The downside is you have to add an extra element to the dom.  I've been using it for years and it even works down to IE 5.5 with a little hack.

```
.parent {
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;          /* height is needed */
    text-align: center;     /* adjust to suit */
    font-size: 0;
}
.parent > * {
    *display: inline;       /* fix for IE 7 and below */ 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom; /* adjust to suit */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.align {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.child {
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;        /* remember to set font-size on html tag */
}
```

and the markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="align"></span>
    <img class="child" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
</div>
```